How can I customize the style of FullCalendar?
I'm currently working on a project where I'm using FullCalendar for displaying events. While FullCalendar is a great library, I'm looking to make some specific style customizations to better match the look and feel of my application.
Here are a few things I'm trying to achieve:
Change the background color of the calendar header and cells.
Customize the appearance of the event tooltips and popovers.
Could anyone provide guidance or examples on how to effectively customize the FullCalendar style? Are there specific classes or methods I should use, or best practices for integrating custom styles?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
I have tried overriding the default CSS styles, but I’m not sure if I’m targeting the correct elements or if there’s a more efficient way to apply these styles.
my html & css  :
  <full-calendar
        class="w-full rounded-lg overflow-hidden"
        [options]="calendarOptions"
      ></full-calendar>

  .fc .fc-button-primary {
    background-color: aliceblue;
  }


Have you read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/css-customization yet?

yess , but when i try ican't

Well, what do you mean specifically? Can't what, precisely? What change did you try to make? What code did you use for that? What effect, if any, did you see? We can probably help you to fix your code, if you show it to us. See also [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue, and then [edit] your question. But we certainly won't be able to fix anything if we have no code and only know that you "can't" do something. Thanks :-)

i want to change header button color of header for example , this is my css :
.fc .fc-button-primary {
background-color: aliceblue;
}

As I already mentioned above, please [edit] your question when you have code and new information to share. Don't put it in the comments. Stackoverflow is not a forum :-)

okii , thank u , i already add the pics of my code

Did you read [ask] before updating your question, as I suggested? It tells you not to post images of code, data or error messages. This information is text-based. Pasting it as graphics is very impractical as it can't be copied, searched, re-used in answers etc. It makes it difficult for those who might want to help you. Please [edit] your question to include the code as text and use the formatting tools to present it nicely, so that it is usable for those who want to help you. Thanks

(See also Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? for more info)

Also, one line of CSS is a not a [mre] of your issue! It's minimal for sure, but it's a bit too minimal...

Anyway that CSS you've posted (.fc .fc-button-primary { background-color: aliceblue; }) will definitely change the background colour of the buttons in the calendar - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/zYVWOyO /. But it has nothing to do with the rest of the header, or cell backgrounds, or any of the other things you mentioned. Have you attempted to find out what HTML elements match to those other items and set any CSS rules on them?

wait i update question to more informatiion

I’m not sure if I’m targeting the correct elements...as fullCalendar's guidance says, use the element inspector in your browser's Developer Tools to inspect the various components of the rendered fullCalendar HTML and see which bit you need to target, and what classes, IDs or other properties it has which you could use as a CSS selector.

so like that or ?

Yes like that thanks. So, I've already demonstrated what effect the btn-primary class will have. Have you actually tried any others?

i already tried  , but the btn doesn't change

It does - I proved that in the demo link I gave you (https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/zYVWOyO). If it doesn't change for you, then you must have some different setup - either some other CSS overriding it, or maybe a different version of fullCalendar, or some other difference in the environment. It's hard to be sure. But evidently the code you've given us isn't a [mre] of that issue, by itself.

i use angular , so the in the html it's only the code i already given , and in components ,  i only have the calendar option, or i need more setup in angular

I realise that the fullCalendar setup doesn't require you to write anything beyond what you've shown - it then uses JS to render the rest of its HTML, which you can inspect in your browser's tools once it's loaded. But like I said already: what version of fullCalendar are you loading? Does your page have any other additional CSS beyond just what is included with fullCalendar?

thankss , but i already found how it works

 "styles": [
              "src/app/components/calendar/calendar.component.css",
            ],

I finally found how it works, you add the style you want in angular.json , and we can override the css after that

Ah, so it sounds like the issue was that the CSS you'd written was not actually being applied because you hadn't included it in the Angular config?

yess , i need to include i the css to style in angular json
